# Android Position Button after animation (view.layout())

Tags: android, animation, layout

I know, that I have to reposition the actual view after the animation, to make it clickable afterwards. The solution I found was to use .layout(l,t,r,b) method of the view.

But what is happening now is, that the view animates correctly 150px upwards, but then (when calling above mentioned method) jumps up another 150px. So the "hitbox" of my view is now where I'd expect it to be, but the rendered image of my view is above it.

By clicking the hitbox, the view starts by animating down 150px, and then again takes a jump of 150px.

Here are two pictures to illustrate my problem. The second pictues shows how it looks after the "up-animation". The red rectangle shows where I'd want the image to be.

Before:
[image: Before animation]

After:
[image: After animation]

Here are the important code lines:

```
animSlideUpButton = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -150);
animSlideDownButton = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -150, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);

animSlideUpButton.setDuration(1000);
animSlideDownButton.setDuration(1000);

animSlideUpButton.setFillAfter(true);
animSlideDownButton.setFillAfter(true);

animSlideUpButton.setAnimationListener(this);
animSlideDownButton.setAnimationListener(this);
```

Listener:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(animation == animSlideUpButton){
        int left = containerBttToggleFooter.getLeft();
        int top = containerBttToggleFooter.getTop();
        int right = containerBttToggleFooter.getRight();
        int bottom = containerBttToggleFooter.getBottom();

        containerBttToggleFooter.layout(left, top-150, right, bottom-150);

    }else if(animation == animSlideDownButton){
        int left = containerBttToggleFooter.getLeft();
        int top = containerBttToggleFooter.getTop();
        int right = containerBttToggleFooter.getRight();
        int bottom = containerBttToggleFooter.getBottom();

        containerBttToggleFooter.layout(left, top+150, right, bottom+150);

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `fillAfter` with the animation, so the translations remain 150 after the animation ends, and on top of that, you're shifting them an additional 150 via the onAnimationEnd method.

To fix this, change this code:

```
animSlideUpButton.setFillAfter(true);
animSlideDownButton.setFillAfter(true);
```

to this:

```
animSlideUpButton.setFillAfter(false);
animSlideDownButton.setFillAfter(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it! But now there's a little flicker between the animation resetting the view, and me setting the new layout in the onEndAnimation-Listener.

Comment: try adding a call to clearAnimation() on the view in the onAnimationEnd method.